# Android: How Do I Synchronize Data From Server To My App Every 3 and 5 Minutes?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have a JSON data in a PHP and MySQL website. Now I want to synchronize my data in an Android App every 3 and 5 minutes.

The application will check every 3 and 5 minutes if there's an update in website data.

How can I do that?

Comment: Run a service using the android app and check on server. Do a callout in the background to your server and check for the update.

Comment: @Adnan-Mulla: do you have tutorial or example for that?

Comment: Here is a simple one : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/     You need to do the same in a service.        Another tutorial for service : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: It would be great if you could accept one of the answers and close this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run a service using the android app and check on server. Do a callout in the background to your server and check for the update. Here is a simple one : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/                              You need to do the same in a service. Another tutorial for service : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Hope this helps!